# How to use managed identity to connect to Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

In the docs they give an example of how to connect to a hub by using a connection string that contains a Shared Access Signature. So far in my app, I've been able to avoid storing secrets myself by just using managed identities. Is there a way to connect to a Notification Hub with a managed identity instead of a secret? I'd rather not do my own secret management.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to list of supported [Azure services that support managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) for Azure resources it seems not available for it.

You may share your feedback by creating a [Feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/405a1b30-8b26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789#) and upvote it. The product group monitors this site for feedback. This is the best way to ensure you are heard and you may receive a response depending on how much they information they can currently share.

Comment: Posted https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/dd259ed7-c68b-ec11-a81b-6045bd7956bb

Answer (score 0):

[Authorization Rules (a.k.a. Access Policies) are associated with a hub and can be accessed using Azure Resource Manager calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/notification-hubs/get-authorization-rule), which I believe supports managed identity. I've thought about this but haven't tried it myself. So please report back if it works for you.